# Create pip package that create a script executable from everywhere

Tags: python-packaging

I created a python script that i want to execute in my terminal, and i want it to be installable with pip

```
pip install utility
utility
```

i already tried to search on internet, but found nothing

Comment: What is the build back-end? Is it setuptools, Poetry, something else? If you have a `setup.py` file, edit your question and copy-paste the content of `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your script not an installable package on pip. If you want to execute the script from anywhere from the terminal you could try by adding the script to Path.

Comment: ok, but i want to add it to the python script folder when i install my package

Comment: @Sniper10754 Where it's installed now?